# Text file is not downloading in spring mvc 3

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-mvc

> I am able to create the file but not able to download it. I am trying to download the file by an ajax call. I am able to receive the file name and file content and successfully able to write the content in a file in application directory but I'm not able to download that file. My code is given bellow :-

The Ajax Code -:

```
downloadButton.onclick = function() {
        //alert(payLoadID); 
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "payloadAjax",
                 data: { payloadData: document.getElementById("modal_paragraph").innerHTML, id: payLoadID },
                 success : function(data) {
                    alert("SUCCESS: " +data);
                //  modal.style.display = "none";
                //  $("body").css("overflow","auto");
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert("ERROR: "+ e);
                },
                done : function(e) {
                    alert("DONE");
                }
            }) 

    }
```

> Here is the java code -:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payloadAjax", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)//, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody
void download(@RequestParam("payloadData") String payloadData, @RequestParam("id") String fileName, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("id : " +fileName);
    System.out.println("payloadData : " +payloadData);

    /* File creation code is here. */
    String FOLDER = "/downloadDir";
    String FILE_NAME = fileName +".txt";

    String appPath = request.getRealPath("");
    System.out.println("appPath = " + appPath);

    File downloadDirectory = new File(appPath + FOLDER);
    if(!downloadDirectory.exists() || !downloadDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        downloadDirectory.mkdir();
        System.out.println("Directory Created");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Directory already exists.");
    }

    File uploadFile = new File(downloadDirectory, FILE_NAME);

    if(uploadFile.exists()) {
        uploadFile.delete();
        System.out.println(uploadFile.getName() +" Has been deleted.");
    }

    try {
        uploadFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("New File successfully created.");

    try
    {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(uploadFile, "UTF-8");
        writer.println(payloadData);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        System.out.println("File successfully written.");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (uploadFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Upload file exists. Ready to download....");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry File not found!!!!");
    }

    /*File creation code successfully completed.*/

    /*File download code starts here */

    /*HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    headers.setContentLength(uploadFile.length());
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "Soubhab_Pathak.txt");
    InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(uploadFile));
    return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, headers, HttpStatus.OK);*/

    if(response == null) {
        System.out.println("Response is null.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Response is not null.");
    }

    System.out.println("111");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println("112");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    System.out.println("113");
    response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FILE_NAME);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", uploadFile.length() +"");
    FileCopyUtils.copy(in, out);
    System.out.println("114");
    response.flushBuffer();
    System.out.println("115"); 
     /*File download code completes here.*/
}
```

> The log is as follows
>   [image]
>
> Any idea?

Comment: You are doing a POST, maybe do a POST then a GET

Comment: Can you add ajax example how you download file?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6090847/matej-marconak ajax code is added and I'm getting success from ajax code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat I changed it to get but still everything is same.

Comment: My suggestion is , bedug the java code , check whether the call is coming to download API and then pointing to correct path.

Comment: Check this AJAX example for download file - https://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/RKxJNo

Comment: able to solve it. Answer I have written bellow. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to solve the problem. This also an example of how to download a string as file in Spring MVC using ajax. Solution is as follows -:

1) one controller action to receive the string from ajax call and store that string in a file in the application server.

2) another controller action where you need to write file download code and this action will receive a GET request.

3) in the ajax call in the success part just call the second action method to download the file.

Now the code is working fine.